# insertar html con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente div:

```
<div id="page-content" class="row-fluid"> </div>
```

Necesito pintar otro div justo encima con js:

```
<div id="headerImage"></div>
```

quedando así:

```
<div id="headerImage"></div>
<div id="page-content" class="row-fluid"> </div>
```

Sé que necesito seleccionar el div page-content mediante document.getElementById("page-content"). Pero luego no sé cómo decirle que el nuevo div lo inserte justo encima.

¿Cómo lo hago con javascript SIN JQUERY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debería de funcionarte sin problemas:

```
document.body.onload = addElement;


function addElement () { 
// crea un nuevo div 
// y añade contenido 
var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hola!¿Qué tal?"); 
newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //añade texto al div creado. 

// añade el elemento creado y su contenido al DOM 
var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!! He tenido que cambiar la útima línea y poner el padre directo del currentDiv. Es lo único.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Me alegra haber ayudado. Suerte!

Comment: ¿Cómo podría añadir un id o class al newDiv?

Comment: Ok solucionado también!!! 
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "headerImage");

Comment: Excelente!!!

Para otros casos tambien puede usar lo sgte: [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)